# How to call a class' constructor to 'create' from Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**Question:**
How can I create a `var a1 = Animal('red', 4, 'frank);` from the console in chrome??

I've created a class while playing around with es6.

```
"use strict";
class Animal{
    constructor(color, legs, name){
        this.color = color;
        this.legs = legs;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
export default Animal;
```

**chrome console** Input + Error

```
>  var frank = new Animal('red', 4, 'henry');
Uncaught ReferenceError: Animal is not defined
at <anonymous>:2:17
at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)(anonymous function) @ VM13736:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM13308:895InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM13308:828InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM13308:694
```

**Index.html**

```
    <script src="../jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="../config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('reflect-metadata')
            .then(function(){
                return System.import('client/app/animal/animal');
            })
            .then(function(Animal){
               window.Animal = Animal;

            })
            .catch(console.log.bind(console));
    </script>
```

UPDATE:
*I've updated the second promise to set Animal to window && I've tested in console.  :( no luck still*
[image: object is not a function]

This is what BableJs would downcompile a class to:

```
var Animal = function Animal(color, legs, name) {


    this.color = color;
    this.legs = legs;
    this.name = name;
};
```

[image]

Comment: As a first step I would suggest to check the support in your chrome version as here: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the `System` API, but it seems reasonable to assume that the promise is resolved with the module. To access it as a global variable from the console, you can assign it to `window`.

You mention that you are using Babel. Babel assigns the default export to the `default` property of the module:

```
System.import('client/app/animal/animal').then(function(module) {
    window.Animal = module.default;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but not after"?

Comment: Let's disregard what I said there as it was a mistake.  I've updated the question above with your answer.  Unfortunately I'm still haven't trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Well, what's the value of `Animal` here? Maybe the constructor is a property of that object instead.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to ask?  I've updated what BableJS would compile a class down to.

Comment: I want to beable to create new Animal() 's from the chrome console for testing.

Comment: I'm asking what the value of `Animal` is in `.then(function(Animal){ ... })` (yeah, that wasn't clear). Since you mention Babel, I assume you have to do `window.Animal = Animal.default;`.

Comment: There you go, `Animal.default` it is. I'll update my answer (and choose less confusing variable names).

Comment: It's not only Babel, is it? Every ES6 implementation should assign the default export to the `default` property of the module object.

Comment: @Bergi: ModuleRecords actually have a very different structure: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-source-text-module-records. So no, I wouldn't say that this how it must be implemented, but it's convenient.

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly an object, but still the default export has `"default"` for its [[ExportName]]; it just a normal export with an uncommon name. You can even do `import {default: Animal} from 'animal';` :-)